# 403 Forbidden Spring Boot Web Socket Call

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-boot, cors, spring-websocket

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE. My code is based on the Starting Guide for websocket in Spring Boot using Stomp and SocketJS.

When I run the Client from localhost:8080 (Spring Server)... Of course it works. Its not until I try to call it from a Different Port, that I get a 403 Forbidden. My CorsFilter is set below.

[Getting Started Web Sockets With Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

## My Client is ....http://localhost:3000

## My Spring Boot Server is ... http://localhost:8080

I setup my CorsFilter to access my client...

## CorsFilter

```
package hello;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsFilter.class);

    public CorsFilter() {
        log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        String clientOrigin = request.getHeader("origin");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", clientOrigin);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET,  DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, " +
                        "Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

## Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
```

## Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET,  DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 02 Dec 2015 13:59:25 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: maybe you are missing `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");` ?

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: nope, I updated what I added.

Comment: Try adding this in your WebSocket configuration class (AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer) in method `registerStompEndpoints` add `setAllowedOrigins("*")`.


For example
       `registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();`

Answer (score 25):

Adding an answer in case anyone else comes across this question. As suggested in the comments, you need to use the `setAllowedOrigins` method as described in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-allowed-origins). So assuming that [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) is the tutorial you are following, you would end up with a configuration class that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/your/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/yourapp");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/your/endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000").withSockJS();
  }

}
```

That would allow a stomp client running on localhost:3000 to subscribe to the `/your/endpoint`.

Comment: Spice can i use separate ports for websocket and http in spring boot

Comment: @naila Configuring your spring boot application to listen to multiple ports is discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357135/configure-spring-boot-with-two-ports

Comment: This only works for localhost, I always get CORS error when I call websocket hosted on a server such as `https://example.com/my-rest-app/websocket`